# How to cross check values in one column in a file in another file and print the missing values?

Tags: awk, grep, text-processing

I have a file that looks like this. It has  12 columns and 3244343 rows. Lets call this file 1.

```
variant_id  gene_id tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se    pval_nominal_threshold  min_pval_nominal    pval_beta
chr10_100000235_C_T_b38 ENSG00000227232.5   35211   73  74  0.061157    1.69779e-08 0.510322    0.0890939   0.0006160191.01823e-08  1.17701e-05
chr10_100002628_A_C_b38 ENSG00000227232.5   635545  126 130 0.107438    1.01823e-08 0.405406    0.0696647   0.0006160191.01823e-08  1.17701e-05
chr1_666028_G_A_b38 ENSG00000227232.5   636475  111 115 0.0950413   2.78462e-08 0.411513    0.0729864   0.0006160191.01823e-08  1.17701e-0
```

I have another file that looks like this with 7 headers and with 1633293 rows. This is file 2.

```
"variant_id" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos"
"chr10_100000235_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100000235" "C" "T" "chr10" 101759992
"chr10_100002628_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100002628" "A" "C" "chr10" 101762385
"chr10_100004827_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100004827" "A" "C" "chr10" 101764584
"chr10_100005358_G_C_b38" "chr10" "100005358" "G" "C" "chr10" 101765115
```

I am only interested in the `variant_id` column. This is the  first column in both files.

How can I compare these two columns and only print those `variant_id` values in the first column that are *not found in the second file*. For the above example, the output should be

```
chr1_666028_G_A_b38
```

because it's found in the first file but not the second.

All the values of the `variant_id` in the second file are also in the first file. But there are extra IDs in the first file not present in the second, which I want to identify.

I am using the command below:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' file2 > file2.names
$ grep -vf file2.names file1
```

However, the output is just all the values of **variant_id** in file 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`. Both the codes will print 1st field from file1 if its NOT present in 2nd field, its taking care of addiotnal `"` present before and after $1 in file2.

```
awk '
FNR==1 { next }
FNR==NR{
  gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$1)
  arr[$1]
  next
}
!($1 in arr){
  print $1
}
' file2 file1
```

---

---

***2nd solution*** OR without using `gsub` as used in above `awk` code a slight different from above one, where I am not doing substitution of `"` values present before and after in $1, I am simply wrapping $1 of file1 and checking if that is present in file2 or not here.

```
awk '
FNR==1 { next }
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]
  next
}
!("\""$1"\"" in arr){
  print $1
}
' file2 file1
```

Comment: I don't get an output when doing this. I put this in a script with a #!/bin/bash header and submitted it as a job.

Comment: @HKJ3, could you please run it on terminal itself and please make sure files are passed in same order and same name please. If it's running on your terminal then we can see what's going on in script 

Comment: I typed into the command line directly and I get the following error

Comment: >> awk 'FNR==1 { next } FNR==NR{gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$1) arr[$1] next} !($1 in arr){  print $1}' file2.txt file1.txt > difference.txt

Comment: I get a syntax error ^ (underneath the next).

Comment: @HKJ3, In one-liner you should run it like: `awk 'FNR==1 { next } FNR==NR{gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$1);arr[$1];next} !($1 in arr){print $1}' file2 file1` **AND** `awk 'FNR==1 { next } FNR==NR{arr[$1];next} !("\""$1"\"" in arr){print $1}' file2 file1` Both the solutions let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Is there anything I can do to thank you?

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk 'FNR == NR {gsub(/"/, "", $1); a[$1]; next}
!($1 in a) {print $1}' file2 file1

chr1_666028_G_A_b38
```

Answer (score 3):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]"]' '
    NR==FNR { a[$2]; next }
    !($1 in a) { print $1 }
' file2 file1
chr1_666028_G_A_b38
```

Answer (score 1):

An `awk`-based solution that ensures the missing ones are only printed once :

- *(tested on `mawk` `gawk` and `nawk`)*

|

```
awk -F'[ \t\"]' 'NF = (_=NR==FNR) ? __[$++_]++*!_ : ___[$!_]--==__[$!_]' f2 f1
```

> ```
> chr1_666028_G_A_b38
> ```

alternative less-elegant but single-array approach:

```
awk 'NF = (_=NR==FNR)? __[$++_]++*!_ : (_=NR) == -(__[$!!_]-=_)' f2 f1
```